# Select only 2 rows of data per grouped column

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in my database, for the purposes of discussion let's say they are:

```
USERS   
-----
id
display_name

ROLES
-----
id
role

USER_ROLES
----------
user_role_id
user_id
role_id
```

As you can see 1 user can have multiple roles. Now I have successfully grouped them as their roles with the following query.

```
SELECT r.`name`, GROUP_CONCAT(u.display_name) AS users_for_role
FROM users u,
  roles r,
  user_roles ur
WHERE u.id = ur.user_id
  AND r.id = ur.role_id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

And got the result like

```
| ROLE_USER         | user1,user6,user4 |
| ROLE_CELEBRITY    | user4,user5,user6 |
| ROLE_MUSICIAN     | user4             |
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve is I want to limit the select count to max 2. So my expected result would be ROLE_USER selects only "user1" and "user6" MAX

Comment: That's achievable but is there any specific order to get the first 2 value or you just want any first 2 that appears in the `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: @FaNo_FN they should  ordered by user tables "display_name" column hehe

Comment: So that means if the `GROUP_CONCAT` results is `user1, user6, user4`, then the order should be `user1, user4, user6` correct? So the end result should be `user1, user4`?

Comment: @FaNo_FN yeah that's accurate.

Comment: I see, then like that you can do `GROUP_CONCAT(u.display_name ORDER BY u.display_name) ` in addition to Tim's first answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick you could use here would be to just wrap your current call to `GROUP_CONCAT` with `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, to retain only at most the first two entries:

```sql
SELECT r.name, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(u.display_name), ',', 2) AS users_for_role
FROM users u
INNER JOIN roles r ON u.id = ur.user_id
INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON r.id = ur.role_id
GROUP BY r.id;
```

Another more formal approach would be to use a subquery with `ROW_NUMBER` to restrict to the first two entries per name:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT r.id, r.name, u.display_name,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.name ORDER BY u.display_name) rn
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN roles r ON u.id = ur.user_id
    INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON r.id = ur.role_id
)

SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(display_name) AS users_for_role
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: tnx but i couldn't make it work, im guessing having little bit of alias problem after first cte method second query starts with select not picking aliasses